# How to show that all level curves of $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x^2-y^2+2$ are circumferences?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $f(x,y)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x^2-y^2+2$. Then it's easy to show that $x^2+y^2=h$ is a level curve for $f$, for all $h\in[0,\infty)$. Here I'm saying that all circumferences $\{(x,y,x^2+y^2):x^2+y^2=r^2, r\ge 0\}$ are level curves of $f$. Given the last fact, how can I prove the title? If not, how do I prove that all the level curves of $f$ are circumferences?

I'd have to show that $f(x,y)=k$, $k\in\text{Ran}(f)$ denotes a circumference. I don't know how to write $f$ like $(x-a)^2+(y-b)^2$.

I appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: do you mean $f = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} - (x^2 + y^2) + 2?$

Comment: @abel oh, yes, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function $f$ is defined on all of ${\Bbb R}^2$. Given an arbitrary $C\in{\Bbb R}$ the set
$$L_C:=f^{-1}(C):=\{(x,y)\in{\Bbb R}^2\>|\>f(x,y)=C\}$$
is called the *level set* of $f$ belonging to the value $C$. In the case at hand we have
$$f(x,y):=r-r^2+2\ ,$$
where $r:=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Finding the level set $L_C$ means solving the equation
$$r-r^2+2=C\ .$$
Formally this leads to
$$r={1\over2}\left(1\pm\sqrt{9-4C}\right)\ .\tag{1}$$
But now the work is not over yet. Instead we have to discuss what $(1)$ is telling us for various values of $C$.

When $C>{9\over4}$ then $L_C=\emptyset$.

When $C={9\over4}$ then $L_C$ is a circle of radius ${1\over2}$.

When $2<C<{9\over4}$ then $L_C$ consists of two circles with positive radii.

When $C=2$ then $L_C$ consists of the origin and a circle of positive radius.

When $C<2$ then $L_C$ consists of a single circle.

Answer (score 1):

the level curves of $f$ are given by $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} -(x^2+y^2) = C = \text{ constant}$ this is equivalent to $r - r^2 = C$ for $C > -\frac{1}{4}$ this give $r = \dfrac{1+\sqrt{1+4C}}{2}$ where $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}.$  these are parts of circles of radius greater or equal to ${1}/{2}.$

Comment: Thanks, do you know how could I prove this for $C<-\frac 14$?

Comment: @Vladimir: **abel** got a sign wrong; $r-r^2=C$ is $r^2-r+C=0$, so $r=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{1-4C}}2$, and we need $C\le\frac14$. You don’t have to worry about $C>\frac14$, since $r-r^2$ reaches a maximum of $\frac14$ at $r=\frac12$.